# Android - Loop random array and don't repeat

Tags: android

I am a beginner in Android App development. The code below is a quiz app and I want it to loop random questions and don't repeat the question, I tried to use a flag2 to randomly generate questions but I was getting compile errors, can anyone help me out with this. I'm also a beginner in Java.

```
TextView tv;
Button btn1;
RadioButton rb1,rb2,rb3;
RadioGroup rg;

String Questions[]={"What is 1+1?","Capital of USA?","What is 2+2","Echo with Laughter","Warg"};
String opt[]={"2","3","4", "New York","Washington DC","Maryland", "5","4","6","Stairway to Heaven","Hotel California","Highway to hell","Jon","Bran","Dario" };
String ans[]={"2","Washington DC","4","Stairway to heaven","Bran"};



int flag=0;
public static int correct;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    btn1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
    rg=(RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.radioGroup);
    rb1=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radioButton);
    rb2=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radioButton2);
    rb3=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radioButton3);

    tv.setText(Questions[flag]);
    rb1.setText(opt[0]);
    rb2.setText(opt[1]);
    rb3.setText(opt[2]);

    btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            RadioButton uans = (RadioButton) findViewById(rg.getCheckedRadioButtonId());
            String ansText = uans.getText().toString();

            if (ansText.equalsIgnoreCase(ans[flag])) {
                correct++;
            }
            else {
                Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Token.class);
                startActivity(in);
            }
            flag++;
            if (flag < Questions.length) {
                tv.setText(Questions[flag]);
                rb1.setText(opt[flag * 3]);
                rb2.setText(opt[(flag * 3)+1]);
                rb3.setText(opt[(flag * 3)+2]);
            }
            else {

                Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Token.class);
                startActivity(in);
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT:**

This is due to while goes infinite, New declarations as Lists:

```
   Random random = new Random();
        String rightAnswer=null;
        List<String> questions=new ArrayList<String>(); // list of questions
        List<String> answers=new ArrayList<String>();  // list of answers

    String[] ques={"What is 1+1?","Capital of USA?","What is 2+2","Echo with Laughter","Warg"};
            questions.addAll(Arrays.asList(ques));

    String[] ans={"2","Washington DC","4","Stairway to heaven","Bran"};     
            answers.addAll(Arrays.asList(ans));

    ArrayList<String[]> options = new ArrayList<String[]>(); // list of arrays that holds options

    String[] opt1={"2","3","4"};
    String[] opt2={"New York","Washington DC","Maryland"};
    String[] opt3={"5","4","6"};
    String[] opt4={"Stairway to Heaven","Hotel California","Highway to hell"};
    String[] opt5={"Jon","Bran","Dario" };
    options.add(opt1);
    options.add(opt2);
    options.add(opt3);
    options.add(opt4);
    options.add(opt5);
```

And where you want to generate question you can write this code, I am assuming in onClick() of Button:

```
    int questionNumber;
    if(questions.size()>0) // only run if list contains something
    {

    questionNumber = random.nextInt(questions.size());  // generate random question from current list

    String[] currentOptions=options.get(questionNumber);

    tv.setText(questions[questionNumber]);
    rb1.setText(currentOptions[0]);
    rb2.setText(currentOptions[1]);
    rb3.setText(currentOptions[2]);


    rightAnswer=answers.get(questionNumber); // hold right answer in this variable

    questions.remove(questionNumber); // remove question which is asked
    answers.remove(questionNumber);   // remove answer which is asked
    options.remove(questionNumber);   // remove options that are showed   


    }
    else
    {
     tv.setText("No questions remaining");
    }
```

This is tested, and I was able to get these results:
[image]

**NOTE:** Declaration part must be outside the function that generates random question, otherwise it will fail.

Comment: This worked for me, but I can't seem to go to the next question and it gives me the error "Too much output".

Answer (score 1):

use java.lang.Math.random().
it will return values from 0.0 to 0.1 convert those values in integer & get the question of the integer

Answer (score 1):

Generate random number within the range which here would be from 0 to Maximum number of question, you can do it like below:

```
int numberOfQuestion = 5; 
Random rn = new Random();
randomNum = rn.nextInt() % numberOfQuestion; // random number from 0 to MaxRange - 1
```

Instead of using three arrays you can create a class:

```
class Quiz{
    String question;
    String answer;
    String[] options;
    boolean asked;
}
```

And every time when the particular question is asked just make the flag `asked` to true, and before asking question just check if that question is asked or not, if not then only display the question.

Answer (score 1):

Three string array actualy useless. You should use object ArrayList.

```
public class QuestionObject{
    int id;
    String question;
    String [] options;
    String answer;
    --you should implement getter and setter--
    public int getId(){
       return this.id;
    }
    public void setId(int id){
      this.id= id;
    }
    public String getQuestion(){
       return this.question;
    }
    public void setQuesion(String question){
      this.question = question;
    }
   public String[] getOptions() 
   { 
      return options; 
   } 

  public void setOptions(String[] options) 
 { 
   this.options= options; 
   } 

  public int getOptionsElement(int location) 
   { 
      return options[location]; 
  } 

  public void setOptionsElement(int value, int location) 
  { 
    options[location] = value; 
  }
    public String getAnswer(){
       return this.answer;
    }
    public void setAnswer(String answer){
      this.answer= answer;
    }
}
```

And you should use this like

```
ArrayList<QuestionObject> questionObject = new ArrayList<QuestionObject>();
ArrayList<QuestionObject> answeredQuestion = new ArrayList<QuestionObject>();
```

**Don't forget fill the questionObject with your Question options and aswers.**

After that your logic must be implement.you can take the id of question when question display and remove the list. May be you can push the removed question another Arraylist.

```
//take the diplaying question this id can be your random number
int id = questionObject.getId(); //or int id = yourRandomNumber;
//store the another arraylist this question
answeredQuestion.add(questionObject.get(id));
//remove it from list than never show again 
questionObject.remove(id);
```

I think this may help you.